# Reserved keyword as identifier in JPA query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, naming, reserved-words

I defined multiple JPA named queries this way:

```
SELECT group FROM FOO_Group group WHERE group.valid = :valid ORDER BY group.date
```

Even though `group` is a reserved keyword in SQL, this never seemed to bother Hibernate.

Now, however, I had to define a named query that joins two tables:

```
SELECT group FROM FOO_User user JOIN user.group group WHERE group.valid = :valid ORDER BY group.date
```

This time the query fails and Hibernate states that `BY` was expected (as in `GROUP BY`), but `WHERE` was found.

**I know that using reserved keywords as column, table or entity names is generally a bad idea.** But I wonder, why it did not cause any trouble in my old queries, but now fails in the joining query. Is there any syntax that allows me to use `group` in the new query as well? I tried `JOIN user.group AS group`, but that did not work out as expected.

Right now, all I can do is renaming the identifier:

```
SELECT g FROM FOO_User user JOIN user.group g WHERE g.valid = :valid ORDER BY g.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should distinguish *SQL key words* and *JPQL/HQL reserved identifiers*.

You can use [SQL quoted identifiers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers) for column/table names.

But according to the JPA specification (see section *4.4.1 Identifiers*)

> Reserved identifiers **must not be used** as identification variables
>   or result variables (see section 4.8).

Your first query worked just by chance. The HQL grammar is specified [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/antlr/hql.g). As you can see from the [HqlParser](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/HqlParser.java) implementation the `group` belong to so called weak keywords (see the `weakKeywords()` method). So, the first query was tokenized in the following way:

```
SELECT group               --> selectClause                
FROM FOO_Group group       --> fromClause   (FROM^ { weakKeywords(); }) ...
WHERE group.valid = :valid --> whereClause
ORDER BY group.date        --> orderByClause
```

But the second one:

```
SELECT group             --> selectClause
FROM FOO_User user       --> fromClause FROM^ { weakKeywords(); }
JOIN user.group          ----> fromJoin ... JOIN^ (FETCH)? joinPath (asAlias)? ...
group                    --> problem !!!
WHERE group.valid = :valid
ORDER BY group.date
```

Comment: All right, thanks for the insights and the referenced grammar. I was aware that, as a reserved keyword, the identifier `group` was probably a bad choice. However, I wondered why it worked nonetheless once and failed the other time. I now renamed both `group` and `g` to `grp` to accomplish a consistent naming scheme.